# Embedding an IDE into a Python GUI

Tags: python

How do I embed an IDE such as IDLE into to a python GUI? I'm thinking of using WXpython, I want half GUI to fill the IDE console and the other half to represent any code implemented in the console. I want this to link to a library I'm writing in Python. I've tried browsing but they sound complicated like using C. Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: You want to make Python IDE?

Comment: Yeah, but is there existing systems to allow me to do this?

Comment: Yes there are :) Take a look at the wxPython Demo (wxPython-x.x.x.x-demo/samples/ide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wxPython demo to get some useful code snippets. Take a look at `wxPython-x.x.x.x-demo/samples/ide`. You can get wxPy demo [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-demo-2.8.12.1.tar.bz2).

Comment: Is there a support for python 3.3 ? Also are there tutorials to get started?

Comment: @Pro-grammer, take a look here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix. wxPy-Phoenix runs on Py3. And here is the tutorial: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started; Or: http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial; Or: http://zetcode.com/wxpython/. Also don't forget to take a look here: http://bit.ly/H4BuZx

Answer (score 0):

The wxPython demo is a fair example of doing something like this as it lets you edit and run code, add in pygments for syntax highlighting and you are a lot of the way there.